# Different colors for parent category of a matrix visual

Tags: powerbi

How to set up different colors for parent category of a matrix visual. I want to achieve this:
[image]

In Power BI matrix visual, it looks like this:
[image]

With larger number of items within category, it is hard to spot where one category (Fruits) finishes and the other (Vegetables) starts.

I am pretty aware that the desired solution is impossible. I will welcome any dirty workarounds. I know that putting category to rows works much better in terms of visibility. But the requirement is columns, not rows.

Data to replicate:

```
DATATABLE (
    "Store", STRING,
    "Category", STRING,
    "Product", STRING,
    "Sales", INTEGER,
    {
        { "Store 1", "Fruits", "apple", "1" },
        { "Store 1", "Fruits", "banana", "1" },
        { "Store 1", "Fruits", "cherry", "3" },
        { "Store 1", "Vegetables", "pumpkin", "1" },
        { "Store 1", "Vegetables", "beet", "1" },
        { "Store 1", "Vegetables", "onion", "2" },
        { "Store 2", "Fruits", "apple", "3" },
        { "Store 2", "Fruits", "banana", "3" },
        { "Store 2", "Fruits", "cherry", "1" },
        { "Store 2", "Vegetables", "pumpkin", "2" },
        { "Store 2", "Vegetables", "beet", "2" },
        { "Store 2", "Vegetables", "onion", "3" }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting possible workarounds which, by no means, are satisfactory answers to the question. I post it in hope that it may inspire you to come up with something better.

**Workaround 1 - Pipes**

This solution involves adding a pipe | symbol as the last item in the Product list and tweaking a measure to return the pipe symbol for this dummy pipe product. It presents like this:

[image]

To achieve this nasty looking matrix, we need to do 2 things. First, create a dimension 'Products' with dummy product items appearing as |. The | product must be in each category. Since all products must be unique, we use a technique to make them distinct.

Add this as a DAX table:

```
Products = 
var WhiteSpace = UNICHAR(127)
var ZeroWidthSpace = UNICHAR(8203)
var z1 = "|" & REPT( ZeroWidthSpace, 1 ) 
var z2 = "|" & REPT( ZeroWidthSpace, 2 ) 

return
    UNION(
        DATATABLE(
            "Category", STRING,
            "Product", STRING,
            "Sort", INTEGER,
            {
                { "Fruits", "apple", "1" },
                { "Fruits", "banana", "2" },
                { "Fruits", "cherry", "3" },
                { "Vegetables", "beet", "4" },
                { "Vegetables", "onion", "5" },
                { "Vegetables", "pumpkin", "6" }
            }
        ),
        ROW( "Category", "Fruits", "Product", z1, "Sort", 7 ),
        ROW( "Category", "Vegetables", "Product", z2, "Sort", 8 )
    )
```

Products should be sorted by the 'Sort' column so that pipes appear at the end of the product list.

[image]

The following measure returns pipes, if the product is a pipe itself, otherwise it returns the value :-)

```
Measure = 
var ZeroWidthSpace = UNICHAR(8203)
var z1 = "|" & REPT( ZeroWidthSpace, 1 ) 
var z2 = "|" & REPT( ZeroWidthSpace, 2 ) 
var Current_Product = SELECTEDVALUE( 'Products'[Product] )
return
    IF( Current_Product in { z1, z2 }, "|", [Sale] )
```

**Workaround 2. Multiple Measures**

The second workaround achieved by creating different measures, one for each category and hiding the empty columns. It allows to produce this result:

[image]

```
M_cat_1 = IF( SELECTEDVALUE( Products[Category] ) =  "Fruits", [Sale] )
M_cat_2 = IF( SELECTEDVALUE( Products[Category] ) <> "Fruits", [Sale] )
```

Then we apply the setup to each of the measures:

[image]